# How to make a bot respond if somebody mentions the bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make my bot respond if somebody mentions the bot. My current code is this

```
 if message.content.startswith('@435379055253127178'):
    text = await client.send_message(message.channel, "**Baking a cake**")
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "**Baking a cake**")
    await client.edit_message(text, "Hi i'm cake bot nice to meet you!")
```

However, I got no response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mentions are stored in an attribute named [`message.mentions`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions)

```
if discord.utils.get(message.server.members, '435379055253127178') in message.mentions:
    text = await client.send_message(message.channel, "**Baking a cake**")
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "**Baking a cake**")
    await client.edit_message(text, "Hi i'm cake bot nice to meet you!")
```

But if you want to check mentions manually instead, there's sometimes a ! in between the @ and id and they are wrapped by <>. I would use a regex:

```
from re import match

if match("<@!?435379055253127178>", message.content) is not None:
    text = await client.send_message(message.channel, "**Baking a cake**")
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "**Baking a cake**")
    await client.edit_message(text, "Hi i'm cake bot nice to meet you!")
```

This will check if the mention of the user is at the front of the message, similar to what you were trying to do. Since `.mentions` keeps a unordered list of all mentioned users.

Btw, if the id is the bot's, you could don't have to hard code the id.

```
if client.user in message.mentions:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to do this seems to be as follows:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
        await message.channel.send("hello!")
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the way I do it can't tell if its the best way

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">")

@client.event    
async def on_message(message):
    for x in message.mentions:
        if(x==client.user):
            await message.channel.send(f":sauropod: did someone mention me?")

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

by the way, u don't have to use the prefix while sending a message unlike commands for this to work. the code will trigger no matter where the bot is mentioned in the message